# mxGraph / draw.io : change edge color when it connected to shape

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, draw.io

I'm starting to work on integrating the draw.io editor into my project https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/tree/dev/src/main/webapp

my objective is to change the edge (arrow) color when is connected to a shape (both side)

so i cherched in https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/blob/dev/src/main/webapp/js/grapheditor/Graph.js
for the method responsable for the connection using console.log without success

Any idea how to detect edges connection to anchor points of vertices?

i cherched for `graph.connectCell` but i didn't find it in the code
all i found is `dropAndConnect` used in `itemClicked` in

> Sidbar.js https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/blob/dev/src/main/webapp/js/grapheditor/Sidebar.js#L3485

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach:

diagrams.net ➜ **[Demo](https://viewer.diagrams.net/?highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&nav=1&title=stackoverflow_72479819_Inherit_edge_styles#Uhttps%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fuc%3Fid%3D1e4lMZEbtd1KkHtZ74tW-RWgsFqrG28YA%26export%3Ddownload)**

#### Description:

1. We want all edges to have the same style definition.

   `strokeColor` should change based on the target shape. In order to inherit the color, wrap shapes into swimlanes which behave like "groups". Shape(s) and edges created from shapes can now inherit their color definition from their nearest parent swimlane.

   Edge style:

   ```json
   strokeColor=indicated;indicatorColor=swimlane;
   ```
2. New Edges created from shapes (blue arrows) either have the [default diagram styles](https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/configure-diagram-editor#format) or get their styles from source shape if there is a definition for `newEdgeStyle={....}`

   ```json
   newEdgeStyle={"edgeStyle":"orthogonalEdgeStyle","html":1,"strokeColor":"indicated","indicatorColor":"swimlane"};
   ```

#### Basic concept

[image]

#### Custom styling

- Waypoints can either be swaped with *real* shapes, or additional shapes can be added to a swimlane.
- Swimlanes can be hided for users since they just hold the `fillColor` and `strokeColor` configuration.

[image]